# Nginx not forwarding requests to backup upstream when port still bound but application not responding

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

My nginx only forwards requests to the backup upstream application when the primary app is stopped oder does not respond at all. When, for example, the application is fighting a "near out-of-memory"-situation it still binds the port and requests somehow don't get redirected to the backup app, as they should because of the proxy_timeout settings.

I'm able to reproduce the scenario with kill -STOP:

```
kill -STOP 34996 #PID of primary app
telnet localhost 20401 
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost. #application port still there
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Browser requests just time out and are not being forwarded to the backup application instance.

Nginx even logs the timeout, but further requests also go to the stuck server and are not forwarded to the backup instance:

```
2016/08/22 14:16:03 [error] 104988#104988: *20813541 upstream timed out    (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 4.3.2.1, server: ~^(test\d*\.)?(example).(com), request: "HEAD /status-tocco HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:16010/app-status", host: "myjavapp.example.com"
```

I would have supposed that the first request after freezing the primary instance should fail after 3s (due tue *proxy_connect_timeout*), during the next 500 seconds (*fail_timeout*) all subsequent requests should go to the backup instance, and only after that additional requests should get to the original server, am I seeing this right?

When I completely stop the java process all requests are immediately redirected to the backup server without any problems.

This is the relevant part of the config:

```
upstream test {
    keepalive 10;
    server 127.0.0.1:20401 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=500s; #local, main instance
    server app06:16010 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=500s backup; #backup instance, different server
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://test;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    proxy_connect_timeout 3s;
    proxy_send_timeout 3s;
    proxy_read_timeout 60s;       
    proxy_http_version 1.1; #keepalive
    proxy_set_header Connection ""; #keepalive

    add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status; # Request served by Cache?
    add_header X-AppServer $upstream_addr; # Backend Server / Port
    add_header X-AppServer-Status $upstream_status; # Backend HTTP Status
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000;" always;
}
```